# jQuery: append and replace content

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

I'm having some trouble appending and replacing content with a click event. There are divs in rows of 3, in between every row is a hidden div with a 100% width, clicking on one of the divs will show the closest hidden div, reload the masonry plugin, and append the relevant content inside it.
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wUEkE/9/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var $container = $('#listings-wrap');

$(function(){
 $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $('#listings-wrap').masonry({
    itemSelector : '.listings-item, .preview-listing',
    columnWidth: 4,
    gutterWidth: 10,
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: true
  });
});
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".listings-item").click(function() {

$('.test').hide();  
    $(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').removeClass('hidden').addClass('preview-listing').append($('#post'+$(this).attr('hook')).show()).hide().delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
 $('#listings-wrap').masonry('reload');
 });

});
```

As you can see, my problem lies when clicking a `.listing-item` when `.hidden` is already shown, instead of replacing the content inside the nearest `.hidden` div, it doesn't work and merely places in the content at the top.
The idea is that there will be a .hidden div after every row, and for example clicking on one of the first 3 `.listing-item` will append the relevant content into the first instance of `.hidden`, clicking on 4 through to 6 will append it into the second instance of `.hidden` etc. But I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: If you click on 4 to 6, do you want the `.hidden` for 1 to 3 to disappear if it was visible?

Comment: @tcovo yes, I only want one `.hidden` to be shown at a time, but after one `.listing-item` has been clicked, if you click another one it fails to replace the div in the `.hidden` container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the jsfiddle. I made some changes which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wUEkE/10/

The main problem was that you called `removeClass('hidden')`, so the `nextAll('.hidden:first')` call didn't work for preview-listings which had already been shown (the selector didn't find the right preview-listing because it didn't have the "hidden" class anymore).

I changed it so that the preview-listings always have the `preview-listing` class, so we can easily select them regardless of whether they're shown or not. Another missing aspect was to hide the other preview-listing if it was already shown. This is what the body of the click handler looks like now:

```
$('.test').hide();
var previewForThis = $(this).nextAll('.preview-listing:first');
var otherPreviews = $(this).siblings('.preview-listing').not(previewForThis);
otherPreviews
    .addClass('excluded') // exclude other previews from masonry layout
    .hide();
previewForThis
    .removeClass('excluded')
    .append($('#post' + $(this).attr('hook')).show())
    .hide()
    .delay(400)
    .fadeIn("slow");
$('#listings-wrap').masonry('reload');
```

I also changed masonry's itemSelector to:

```
'.listings-item, .preview-listing:not(.excluded)'
```

and there are some changes to the html and the css.

Let me know if you have any more questions and I will update this answer.

Comment: perfect! Thanks for that, much appreciated, exactly what I was after.